# With pygsheets how to detect if a spreadsheet already exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, pygsheets

Using pygsheets, I was looking around for a good way to open a Google sheet (by title) if it already exists, otherwise create it.

At the same time, I also wanted to make it r/w to myself and r/o to the rest of the world upon creating it.

Comment: I think that you can also use [`list` method of DriveAPIWrapper](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drive_api.html#pygsheets.drive.DriveAPIWrapper.list) for checking the existence of the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that does just that:

```
import pygsheets

creds_file = "/path/to/your_creds_file.json"

gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=creds_file)

sheet_title = "my_google_sheet"
# Try to open the Google sheet based on its title and if it fails, create it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
try:
    sheet = gc.open(sheet_title)
    print(f"Opened spreadsheet with id:{sheet.id} and url:{sheet.url}")
except pygsheets.SpreadsheetNotFound as error:
    # Can't find it and so create it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    res = gc.sheet.create(sheet_title)
    sheet_id = res['spreadsheetId']
    sheet = gc.open_by_key(sheet_id)
    print(f"Created spreadsheet with id:{sheet.id} and url:{sheet.url}")

    # Share with self to allow to write to it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    sheet.share('YOUR_EMAIL@gmail.com', role='writer', type='user')

    # Share to all for reading                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    sheet.share('', role='reader', type='anyone')

# Write something into it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
wks = sheet.sheet1
wks.update_value('A1', "something")
```